# ASIC verification of a FIFO with "n" unique items

Tags: system-verilog, asic, verification

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frxAta.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have a synchronous FIFO. The depth of the FIFO is 32. Everytime the FIFO has 7  or any "n" unique elements inside it, "unique" signal goes HIGH. How do I test the "unique" signal going high in SystemVerilog or UVM? How would my scoreboard look like?

Comment: An alternative approach might be to use a queue to model the FIFO. Moreover, when every element is pushed into the DUT (and to the reference model/queue), one should check whether there are `n` distinct elements in queue or not (using `unique` built-in method). And expect `unique` signal to be high when the reference model queue has sufficient number of distinct elements. When a read happens, one should pop respective element from the queue.

Answer (score -1):

You don't really need a UVM testbench for a simple test like this. Send in randomized inputs, `predict` when unique should be high, and check if this condition is met.

The key work here is to `predict`. This would be your scoreboard, checker or anything else you want to call it.